# SOAP endpoint in WSO2 APIM fails with null pointer exception

Tags: soap, nullpointerexception, wso2

I'm trying to add a SOAP API to APIM 1.10.0.

First, I'll try to test the SOAP service itself, using the following CURL. The service should return weather conditions of a given city/country:

```
curl -X POST -T soap.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml"  \
      "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"
```

Providing the following soap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
        <CityName>Eilat</CityName>
        <CountryName>Israel</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I receive a sensible response!

Now I introduce this service to APIM, as follows:

```
- Add new API
- I have a SOAP endpoint
    - WSDL URL: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl
    - Start Creating
        - Name: eilat
        - Context: /eilat
        - Version: 1.0.0
        - WSDL: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl  [tested ok]
        - Production Endpoint: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx [valid]
        - Tier Availability: Unlimited
```

I subscribe to this API, and try the following CURL

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <my-key>" -X POST -T soap.xml \
     -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:8280/eilat/1.0.0
```

I get the following reply:

```
<faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
```

Trying the same in SOAP UI, I get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With #status#: HTTP 1.1/500 Internal Server Error

Looking at the logs:

1) http_access_2016-01-17.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2016:16:53:34 +0200] 
         "POST /eilat/1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" - 482 "-" 
         "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) 
         libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"
```

2) wso2-apigw-errors.log

```
2016-01-17 16:53:34,364 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-374] 
    ERROR ServerWorker Error processing 
        POST reguest for : 
           /eilat/1.0.0. Error detail: null. java.lang.NullPointerException
```

3) wso2carbon.log

```
   INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} -  
        Initializing API: admin--eilat:v1.0.0 {org.apache.synapse.rest.API}
   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - 
        'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-01-17 16:52:51,282+0200] 
        {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
   ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  
        Error processing POST reguest for : /eilat/1.0.0. 
        Error detail: null.  
        {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
        java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Looking at the API again, I see that WSDL URL is changed from the URL I provided, to the following:

```
/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--eilat1.0.0.wsdl
```

I guess this is normal behavior.

Question is - why the Null Pointer Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was caused due to a custom authentication plugin handler.
Removing this handler from the chain of handlers solved the problem.